# ES6 function does not have access to `this` while de-structuring the Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I was trying out the below question in ES6 learning material

```
const circle = {
  radius: 10,
  color: 'orange',
  getArea: function() {
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
  },
  getCircumference: function() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
  }
};

let {radius, getArea, getCircumference} = circle;
console.log(getArea())
```

At first I thought the result printed to be `314.1592653589793` but turns out the result printed is `NaN`. Which mean that the `getArea()` function does not have access to `this`. Why does the function do not have access to `this` while de-structuring the Object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Destructuring is just syntactic sugar for assigning object properties to variables, so the following line:

```
let {radius, getArea, getCircumference} = circle;
```

is equivalent to:

```
let radius = circle.radius;
let getArea = circle.getArea;
let getCircumference = circle.getCircumference;
```

Here `getArea` is just a reference to the base-function, which doesn't include the context of `circle`. So your `getArea` variable may as well just be declared like so:

```js
const getArea = function() {
  return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
}

console.log(getArea()); // NaN
```

The `this` in the function is thus determined by the calling context of `getArea` when it is actually *called*. Since no context is provided in the above example, it defaults to the global object of the `window`.

You can specify the `this` of the `getArea()` function later on though by using `.call()`:

```js
const circle = {
  radius: 10,
  color: 'orange',
  getArea: function() {
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
  },
  getCircumference: function() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
  }
};

let {radius, getArea, getCircumference} = circle;
console.log(getArea.call(circle)); // 314.1592653589793
```

Answer (score -1):

This would work as well

```
 const circle = {
      radius: 10,
      color: 'orange',
      getArea() {
        return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
      },
      getCircumference() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
      }
    };
```

Comment: short-hand method names won't make a difference here